# The [gnu-emacs] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed today that we have [a few questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-emacs) tagged  [gnu-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-emacs).

Should we delete this tag, or keep it?

I have no question that tags about specific variants (maybe even builds) are ok. I just wonder whether this specific one isn't too redundant.

Comment: this is MY tag. ;)

Comment: Given all of the options below, I would take a cue from TeX.SX. We have [tag:tex-core] for just this kind of thing – questions about GNU Emacs, but about the thing itself in all of its GNUness.  Similarly, we could have [tag:gnu-emacs-core] and [tag:xemacs-core], but this opens a dangerous door to *all* prepackaged distributions (such as prelude) which should rather be tagged as the component package it is concerning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This tag is mostly redundant and of little use. The vast majority of questions will apply to gnu-emacs.

Of course, there may be questions which pertain only to specific variants, so we could take this tag to mean "specifically not variants". But none (or, arguably, one) of the questions currently tagged as [gnu-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-emacs) fall into this category.
This indicates the tag is likely to be misused much more than it will used accurately.

Furthermore, if we follow askubuntu's example, they do not have an [ubuntu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), while they do have tags for the variants.

Comment: To prove you right, we already have [an example](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/462/search-and-replace-with-camel-snake-case-and-plurals) of [tag:gnu-emacs] used for “I didn't know what tag to use”.

Comment: @Gilles yay! And even I added an excerpt to this tag earlier today, discouraging such usage.

Comment: Though, to be fair, it might not have been approved by the time the question was asked.

Comment: I'm with you, Malabarba. It's a redundant tag that can be applied to too many questions.

Comment: I agree that it's useful, but only if most people don't use it. As such, I would be inclined to *start* the description with the dissuasion: "Do not use this tag. *Unless* ..."

Comment: @Gilles Since this comment that you made, I've fixed about 6 or 7 misuses of this tag (and a few still still got past me), and I haven't seen a single correct use of it. Might it be time to ask this question again?

Comment: @Malabarba Indeed, seeing how it's been so heavily misused (rather predictably), I'm leaning towards getting rid of it. Most threads have an assumption of “recent version of GNU Emacs” anyway.

Comment: After another cull of misused tags, there remain very few that legitimately use [tag:gnu-emacs].  I'd suggest we kill it off and allow people to tag *non*-GNU alternatives like [tag:xemacs] when their questions explicitly address alternate implementations.

Comment: @Dan yes, it's about time we nuke it, I just haven't had the time. You have my support to remove it from existence or to ask the community's help.

Comment: Okay: I've burninated [tag:gnu-emacs].

Answer (score 6):

This tag is meaningful, but it should only be applied to questions that are specifically about GNU Emacs.

- [What functionality is missing in GNU Emacs when compared to XEmacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-functionality-is-missing-in-gnu-emacs-when-compared-to-xemacs) — specifically about GNU Emacs vs XEmacs, so warrants both tags [gnu-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-emacs) and [xemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xemacs)
- [What are the best resources to learn Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/342/what-are-the-best-resources-to-learn-emacs) — doesn't warrant the tag, but this question is unsalvageable and slated for deletion, so its's not worth editing it to tag it correctly.
- [How is the GNU Emacs source code organized?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-is-the-gnu-emacs-source-code-organized) — specifically about GNU Emacs, warrants the tag [gnu-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-emacs)
- [Are there any advantages to using ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead of ~/.emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-emacs-d-init-el-instead-of-emacs) — kinda specific, a borderline case.

Given that there is hardly any viable alternative to GNU Emacs, we could decide to do without this tag, due to the high risk of misuse. Most questions implicitly apply to a reasonably recent version of GNU Emacs anyway.

Comment: The risk of misuse is my main concern. I can see questions 1 and 3, but I see no sense on the 4th.

Comment: I guess we can just wait more and see how it gets used.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really imagine what would be a good use for this tag.
Is there an existing use of this gnu-emacs tag that is useful?
If not, we should just remove it.